# javascript multidimensional array with tags

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

lets say i want an array with a tag name so when i want a specific row i can call it with its tag name, ie myArray['tag_one'][2]  for the tag_one tag i want the 3rd element.

So is there a way i can achieve this?

something like :

```
var myArray=[
        tag_one=[1,2,3],
        tag_two=[11,22,33],
        tag_three=[111,222,333]
]
```

excuse my bad English, thx in advanced

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an [object literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Values,_Variables,_and_Literals#Object_Literals):

```
var myObject = {
    tag_one: [1,2,3],
    tag_two: [11,22,33],
    tag_three: [111,222,333]
}; 

// Using bracket notation:
alert(myObject["tag_one"][0]);  //-> 1

// Using dot notation:
alert(myObject.tag_two[0]);  //-> 11
```